# Search for something in HTML C#

Tags: c#

I have an Html page in string.

```
  <html> 
    .....
    <script>
        {
           http:\\\/\\\/cs513404v4.vk.me\\\/u3692175\\\/videos\\\/49a2e8d28c.720.mp4 
        }
        .....
    </script>
  </html>
```

There is a link in this html page. How can I search for "720.mp4" and take all this link.
Thanks for the HELP.

Comment: Use Regular Expressions

Comment: There is no answer because I don't need an  htmlagilitypack

Comment: @user2660964 if you don't need htmlagilitypack or other html parsing tool, then you don't need html parsing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple regexp will help you.

You are looking for something start with with http and ending with 720.mp4

The example code:

```
string strRegex = @"http.*720.mp4";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"<html> " + "\n" + @"    ....." + "\n" + @"    <script>" + "\n" + @"        {" + "\n" + @"           http:\\\/\\\/cs513404v4.vk.me\\\/u3692175\\\/videos\\\/49a2e8d28c.720.mp4 " + "\n" + @"        }" + "\n" + @"        ....." + "\n" + @"    </script>" + "\n" + @"  </html>";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: What if there is some url at the top of file?

Comment: Relative urls like `/video/1234.mp4` ?

Comment: @I4V if so, we may have some `/video/1234.mp4` as a normal `TEXT`, not a url at all (neither absolute nor relative url).

Comment: @user2660964 just mark it as answer

Comment: @Garath even without testing it?

Comment: @KingKing I should write: you do not need to thanks, if it is ok just mark it as answer